# Everything yet None

Tags: riddle, haiku

> I torture, you learn
>   You think I am not needed
>   But you will thank me
>
> I am what all is
>   Yet I am nonexistent
>   Only minds, I'm in

What am I?

New Verse:

> I'm the foundation
>  Of what? Figure it out! It's
>  Part of the riddle.

Comment: I know what it is...and it's definitely identified by the question. Just because a few people can't figure it out doesn't make it a bad question.

Comment: The answer is Pain
when you get hurt you learn (burn your hand on a fire, you don't touch a fire again)
You think it's unnecessary but you will thank me (pain seems useless but it lets us know we're damaging ourselves)

I am what all is ("Life is pain")
Yet I am nonexistent, only minds I'm in (pain is all in your head)

Comment: @MichaelBrown Your comment just demonstrates why this question was closed as "too broad".  Your solution fits quite well, but the OP indicated (in a comment that has since been deleted) that the "correct" answer is "Knowledge".  There are many possible answers that could fit the question, which makes it too broad for Puzzling.SE.

Comment: Well that's friggin dumb...Knowledge doesn't torture LOL :)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain - wait, the answer was knowledge? That is what I said!

Answer (score 1):

The possible answer to the post is:

> Problem

Added Explanation:

> 'Problem' torture, you learn
>  You think 'Problem' not needed
>  But you will thank 'Problem' (for good/bad experience)
>
>  I am what all is
>  Yet I am nonexistent
>  Only minds, I'm in (Sometime we only think it's problem)

Comment: No. It doesn't really comply with `I am what all is`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's...

> Thoughts?

I torture, you learn

> Thoughts can be terrifying sometimes

You think I am not needed

But you will thank me

> Some people acts before thinking properly about it

I am what all is

> "I think, therefore I am"

Yet I am nonexistent

Only minds, I'm in

> Thoughts only exists in our minds

Comment: You are _very_ close!

Answer (score 0):

> Knowledge

I torture, you learn

> knowledge is learnt

You think I am not needed

> you might not think you need it

But you will thank me

> but it comes in handy

I am what all is

> Knowledge is everything

Yet I am nonexistent
Only minds, I'm in

> But it only exists within the mind - the tripartheid theory of knowledge requires belief, so outside of a believing mind it is just "facts"

The added verse is a bit confusing

> I'm the foundation
> Of what? Figure it out! It's
> Part of the riddle.

but you could say that

> knowledge is the the foundation of everything, civilisation, of success

Answer (score 0):

In a similar vein to the other answers, is it:

> Mathematics

I torture, you learn
You think I am not needed,
But you will thank me

> Mathematics is notoriously torturous to learn, and is stereotypically the thing everyone says they never ended up needing in life as an adult. Even still, mathematics is something we should all be grateful for.

I am what all is
Yet I am nonexistent
Only minds, I'm in

> Almost all things can be described by mathematical patterns or geometries or physics and its laws, which all stem very heavily from mathematics.

I'm the foundation
Of what? Figure it out! It's
Part of the riddle

> Mathematics is the foundational science behind so much. An old xkcd comic I liked joked how psychology is applied biology, which is applied chemistry, which is applied physics, which is all just applied math. Computer science (which is the foundation for this website and thus this puzzle itself) is also clearly linked.